# Insert element in full queue (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm trying to implement a pipeline that receives images from socket clients. I'm currently using a python queue (from queue module) to store the images sent by the clients and to be read by the server. But I'm only interested in the last image sent (added to the queue). The code I'm using for the server is:

```
import threading
from queue import Queue

CLIENTS = 2

queues = [Queue(1) for _ in range(CLIENTS)]

for i in CLIENTS:
    threading.Thread(target=handle,args=(queues[i],)).start() # each client writes to its own queue

while True:
    frames = [q.get() for q in queues]
```

The problem is that when the queue is full, the put method (on client side) waits until it isn't. What I wanted was to implement some structure so that when the queue is full, it simply pops the element and adds the new one from get method (thread safe). This way the queue (size 1) has always the last image received.
I also tried on the client side:

```
with q.mutex:
    if q.full:
        q.queue.clear()
    q.put(image)
```

but it gets stuck in the "q.put(image)".
Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

when you acquire `q.mutex` it would lock the queue, so as long as you are in `with q.mutex` scope you can't do any things with queue like `put` or `get` any more. because `q.put` and `q.get` uses same mutex take a look at [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d48ecebad5ac78a1783e09b0d32c211d9754edf4/Lib/queue.py#L35). you can change your code to something like this:

```
if q.full:
    with q.mutex:
        q.queue.clear()
q.put(image)
```